# Fire an action right after Appearance > Theme Options has been saved

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just started working with Wordpress (v. 3.6.1).
I have OptionTree installed and as it seems it handles the Theme Options page. I want to run my function (in a plugin or wherever else) right after the user saves the changes of this page.
So far I found out that *option-tree/includes/ot-settings-api.php* generates the form and it sets the form action to *options.php* (which is a wordpress core file). I was thinking about change the action to my custom php file and handle the save procedure and finally runs my own function. But this solution looks pretty ugly.
I wonder if there's another way to get the job done.
Thanks.

Comment: Check these : [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API) and [tutsplus](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sheikh Heera link ([tutsplus](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-settings-api-part-1-create-a-theme-options-page/)) I could find a solution.
I think this is some kind of hack and I still don't know if it is the best way. Anyway I did this:

1. Create a file *your-theme-settings.php* in your theme *lib* folder.
2. Let Wordpress knows about your file by adding this code in your theme *functions.php*:

   > ```
   > include_once('lib/your-theme-settings.php');
   > ```
3. Add this code to *your-theme-settings.php*:

   > ```
   > function your_theme_register_settings() {
   >     register_setting('option_tree', 'option_tree', 'your_theme_validate_options');
   > }
   >
   > function your_theme_validate_options($input) {
   >     // do whatever you have to do with $input.
   > }
   >
   > add_action('admin_init', 'your_theme_register_settings');
   > ```

In step 3, I put `'option_tree'` as 1st and 2nd argument of `register_settings` function, because I noticed that the *Option Group* and *Option Name* of OptionTree plugin is `option_tree`.
I'm not sure if this is the best solution, so I would be glad if you shares your ideas.

Comment: Sidenote: `admin_init` only fires on admin side, so no need to check for `is_admin`.